# AngularJS and Coffeescript: I'm confused about model

Tags: angularjs, coffeescript

I'm learning AngularJS (coming from Ruby) and I have some doubt.
I cannot understand the "model" concept.

Example:

Quiz app based on json file with 100 questions.

I want to create quiz with 15 random questions from the json file.

I understand that I must create a Service (or a Factory) that return me the questions for my quiz.

So I have an object and I can use this object for my controllers.

When I finish the quiz and I return the result how can I handle a new quiz?

My object returned from the Service is still there.

In Ruby I create a new instance... but in Angularjs?

Answer (score 0):

You should create a new instance of the model.

So your model would look something like this.

```
var model = function ()
{
    self.Question1 = '';
    self.Question2 = '';
}
```

In your controller you should be using the model in your scope. Once the quiz is finished create a new instance of your model.